# Есть ли способ сделать автоматический поиск и подстановку переменной во всех запросах Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Когда делаем корреляции и, к примеру, используя Regular Expression Extractor вытащили нужную переменную, как найти все места где она используется, чтобы не подставлять ее вручную каждый раз везде? Есть ли какие-то встроенные средства или плагины для более удобного процесса коррреляций?

Answer (score 2):

Касательно наличия встроенных средств - лично я их не нашел, но есть достаточно простой хак. Дело в том, что .jmx по сути представляет собой обычный XML. Так что можно открыть его текстовыс редактором и сделать банальный Find\Replace (Поиск/замену) вписав значение параметра, и название переменной в виде ${VariableName}

Comment: upd в jmeter 4 (по-моему даже раньше появилось - начиная с 3 с чем-то версий) можно сделать поиск/замену по всему сценарию с помощью Ctrl-F